# How do you take the color model used such as AdobeRGB and transfer it into sRGB?

Tags: php, colors, imagemagick, jpeg, imagick

It seems I've ventured into a little-documented area here in imagemagick/imagick.

I'm using php's imagic - not the command line. I have to convert photos that some experienced photographers take, but it converts the color to a model not consistent with what they had used to make their more vibrant photos.

Example: http://www.picturemojo.co.nz/image/muriwai-gannet-colony-auckland-new-zealand/
That photo is actually twice as vibrant and depthy. But the inaccurate color conversion blandifies it.

Comment: Please let me know if this question is unclear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apply built-in color profile to image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646625/apply-built-in-color-profile-to-image)